# Access denied (but not really) when creating elastic beanstalk application version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm *successfully* creating an application version in Elastic Beanstalk with these permissions...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2:<id>:applicationversion/<name>/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2:<id>:application/<name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-<id>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

...and this command:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version \
  --application-name app \
  --version-label v1.2.3 \
  --source-bundle S3Bucket=bucket,S3Key=file.zip \
  --no-auto-create-application \
  --profile admin \
  --process
```

However, the `--process` option causes the aws cli to return an error for some reason:

> An error occurred (InsufficientPrivilegesException) when calling the CreateApplicationVersion operation: Access Denied

Why do I get this error when I can see the new application version (and zip file) show up in Elastic Beanstalk, and why does the error go away when I remove the `--process` option?!

Answer (score 2):

Looking in CloudTrail I saw that together with the `CreateApplicationVersion` action there was always a `CreateBucket` action which was being denied. I inspected the `CreateBucket` action event and it seems like Elastic Beanstalk tries to create its own bucket, and if it exists already nothing happens.

To fix the error message when including `--process` I added the following statement to the policy that was being used to call `aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version`:

```
    {
        "Sid": "AllowEBCreateBucket",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:CreateBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
```

The full policy looks like this:

```
   {
        "Sid": "AllowEBApplications",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateEnvironment",
            "elasticbeanstalk:TerminateEnvironment",
            "elasticbeanstalk:CreateEnvironment",
            "elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:<region>:<account id>:environment/<app name>/*",
            "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:<region>:<account id>:applicationversion/<app name>/*",
            "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:<region>:<account id>:application/<app name>"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowEBDescribe",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "elasticbeanstalk:Describe*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:region>:<account id>:*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowDownloadEBApplicationS3",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-<region>-<account id>/<app name>/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowEBCreateBucket",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:CreateBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
```

Comment: Great answer, as CloudFormation does provide helpful insight on what was failing that the EB dashboard did not provide!